# Read data multiple row array input box and addition eache row textox data

Tags: javascript

I want to multiply 2 input box (requirement and beforewash) and result will be displayed in result input box.

If result below below 5 or more then 5 then Pass/Fail box will display fail either if not then result will be display pass  into pass/fail box for each row and row will be more then one.

**HTML:**

```
 <td><input type="text" class="textbox1" name="mtname[]" value="<?php echo  $dimn->testname; ?>"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="textbox1" name="requerment[]" placeholder="Requerment" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="textbox1" name="beforewash[]" placeholder="Befor  Washt" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="textbox1" name="resultfound[]" placeholder="Result" /></td>
```

[image]

Comment: Please give us any example?

Comment: <td><input type="hidden" class="textbox1" name="mtname[]" value="<?php echo  $dimn->testname; ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" class="textbox1" name="requerment[]" placeholder="Requerment" /></td>
  
<td><input type="text" class="textbox1" name="resultfound[]" placeholder="Result" /></td>
<td> <input type="text" class="textbox1" name="passfail[]" placeholder="Result" />
     </td>

Answer (score 0):

Get the values of two text boxes using

```
    var a = document.getElementById("textBox1Id").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("textBox2Id").value;

    if((a*b)>5){
       document.getElementById("displayResultId").value = "Pass";
    }
    else{
       document.getElementById("displayResultId").value = "Fail";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using html table,
then you can do it like this.

```
var gvDrv = document.getElementById("YourTableID");
    for (var i = 0; i < gvDrv.rows.length-1; i++) {
        var tableRow = gvDrv.rows[i + 1];
        var required=tableRow.cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
        var beforeWash=tableRow.cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
        var result=required*beforeWash;
        tableRow.cells[3].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value=result;
        if(result<5)
          tableRow.cells[4].getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value='Fail';
        else
          tableRow.cells[4].getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value='Pass';
    }
```

Comment: Thank You. Yes i am using html Table